# If Marketplace App project is modified, do domain admins have to re-install the app?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

If I modify the scopes of a Marketplace App project, I understand that domain admins have to re-grant data access to my application. If I make other minor changes such as the app name or setup URL, but leave the scopes as-is, will this affect existing installations in any way?

Answer (score 1):

No, minor changes like that should be fine.